# Google Script - Order of statement execution

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have an issue with script execution. I need help:

I want to set the script name "datasu" & "su" to execute after the previous script execution is completed. Because the script behind will base on the result of the previous script. I have tried using return but it has not worked. Are there any solutions to run & finish the scripts base on order?
Please help me to solve this issue, Thank you so much!

````
  var team_num = team_ss.filter(String).length;
  ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(),23).clearContent();
  var dataena = ss.getRange(2,1,ena.getLastRow(),22).setValues(valueena);
  console.log(team_num);
  var ena = ss.getRange(team_num+1,23,(ss.getLastRow()-team_num),1).setValue('Ena');
  var datasu = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,su.getLastRow(),22).setValues(valuesu);
  var su = ss.getRange(team_num+1,23,(ss.getLastRow()-team_num),1).setValue('SU');```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not super clear what you're trying to do here but try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after the line of code you want to make sure has written to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Oh, flush() is worked. Thank you for your advice Boomer.